# Is there a way Streamlit can show contents of an excel sheet (Graphs, comments and Tables)?

Tags: python, excel, streamlit

I am using Streamlit to show an excel worksheet with Tables, Comments and Graphs as part of an app. I found the easiest way is to convert the excel to a .html file and pass it in components.html but the graphs do not load.
Is there a way Streamlit can show contents of an excel sheet (Graphs, comments and Tables) by either (converting to html or without)? #streamlit #pythonprogramming

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: did you figure something out?

Comment: no, i tried searching all of documentation.